# Validating Of Ideas

Tags: php, mysql, validation, yii

I have a tables named as **ideyalar** and **persons**.

In the registration page users can not create their profile if the username taken before.

And every user can create their ideas. But there I to face the problem that; users CAN CREATE the ideas with the same name. 
I want to restrict this. But I don't know how..

If you help me, I'll be glad.

Thanks. Best regards.

P.S: I should use **CUniqueValidator**, but don't know how..

**IdeyalarController** code:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Ideyalar;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Ideyalar']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Ideyalar'];
        $model->istifade = "1";
        $model->idcontact = Yii::app()->user->getId();

        if($model->save()){
            //  if($model->validate()) {
                    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();
                    $command->insert ('mqrup', array(
                            'idperson'=> Yii::app()->user->getId(),
                            'idideya'=>$model->idideya));

                    $this->redirect(array('viewm','id'=>$model->idideya));
            //  }
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in your model file, not the controller under the method `rules` you should have the following rule:

```
array('your_attribute', 'unique'),
```

So you will have something like

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        //some rules
        array('your_attribute', 'unique'),
    );
}
```

See the [wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/reference-model-rules-validation) for more details